# how to Write global functions to use in all components in angular 6

Tags: localization, angular6

I need to make switch language function global in AppComponent so that I can use it in any component HTML view in the project and need to translate every view without duplicating switcher function and dependencies in all components.

Comment: Hi! For translating Angular applications, check ngx-translate: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core. It's very versatile, as you can use it both in your templates (as a pipe or directive) and in your component's code (as a global service), so I think it will fit your needs. Cheers!

Comment: i  already used ngx-translate , when i tried to use switcher function in app.component.ts , it is not accessible in all other modules views i have to to duplicate it each time i view component file i want to translate text in it , how to make this function global and accessible by every view in application